EDA's on datasets
I have a diabetic dataset here. It contains 0 = nondiabetic, 1= prediabetic, and 2= diabetic. I am trying to do an EDA on the data set. How can I get rid of the prediabetic (#1) data? Is it possible?
diabetes_data is the dataset name. I've split them to get rid of #2 but when going to make plots I am still getting the #1 data. My goal is to exclude #2 because I am trying to find if a person is diabetic or not. Not in between. Any help would be greatenter image description here enter image description here enter image description here
splitting the data into diabetes_no and diabetes_yes. but enter image description herecant seem to figure out how to plot them
